# What is the most easy way to install missing LaTeX packages?

Tags: eclipse, latex

I am using the `Eclipse Plug-in TeXlipse` and would like to know how I can install `LaTeX` packages automatically.

It is quite annoying to download and install a packages, build the document to wait for the next missing package, install that and repeat that process until `pdfLaTeX` is happy.

Answer (score 2):

Metapackage pulling in all components of TeX Live

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

> The TeX Live software distribution offers a complete TeX system. It
>   encompasses programs for typesetting, previewing and printing of TeX
>   documents in many different languages, and a large collection of TeX
>   macros and font libraries. The distribution also includes extensive
>   general documentation about TeX, as well as the documentation
>   accompanying the included software packages.